# Extend the list of MIME-types supported by the builtin uploader in 3.3

Tags: uploads, security

## Goal

I want to be able to extend the list of mime-types supported by the builtin uploader in wp 3.3.1

For example when I try to upload an .apk file to our class blog, I get a
`Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.` error.

## Question

In 3.3 has there been any changes to the way the file type whitelist is managed that is causing me not to be able to fix this?

## Already tried

Activating wp codex and going to the Network Admin Settings page, adding to the Upload file types. That doesn't work, no change.

Also I have tried the 'upload_mimes' method by adding the code to functions.php. That doesn't work, no change.

And lastly I have tried the [PJW Mime Config](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pjw-mime-config/) which doesn't even work for the examples the user provided. Granted this plugin was last edited in 2009

Comment: Feel free to improve the question tags

Answer (score 2):

I've used this to add webm support to the wordpress 3.3.1 uploader.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', array(&$this, 'addUploadMimes'), 1, 1);

public function addUploadMimes($mimes){
         $mimes = array_merge($mimes, array(
                'webm' => 'video/webm'
             ));
            return $mimes;
    }
```

I had to make it run with a high priority to stick.