# Enabling custom file and mime types in multisite

Tags: multisite, uploads, mime-types

I want my multisite network to be able to upload and distribute files that are not allowed by default. In multisite network settings there is a field for adding additional file formats. However this only works for very specific file formats.

According to the advice from [here](https://bionicteaching.com/add-new-mime-type-to-wordpress-multisite/) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40295/239079) I added the following code to my theme's `functions.php`:

```
function my_new_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['pem'] = 'application/x-pem-file';
return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_new_custom_mime_types', 1 );
```

However I still got the same error that I am not allowed to upload such a file. The file type is not listed in the choose file dialog so I have to select `All files (*.*)` or use drag and drop.

Someone had the same problem and had to [adjust the extensions and mime types at five to eight different spaces](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/allowed-file-types-for-upload/). Unfortunately he or she did not publish the solution.

Can anyone list *all* the steps necessary to allow a file type when multisite is enabled?

Edit: Although I tested with extension `.pem` and mimetype `application/x-pem-file` my list of file types is not yet complete so telling *plugin x will enable pem uploads* is not the answer for this question.

Comment: the filter you mentioned is missing, as are the mimetypes you tested with, and the PHP error that generated the error 500 from the error log, can you edit your question to include this information? The steps for a multisite should be the same as the steps for a single site, so the issue here is unlikely to be that you're using a multisite, but with so little technical information it's not possible to write a clear answer.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/421709/edit) to include the `add_filter()` code that caused your 500 error; it might be something that we can help you debug.

Comment: Re: your edit: the [`mime_types` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mime_types/) will allow you to add more MIME types to the default list of allowed MIME types. (That's what filters *do* in WordPress: they allow you to change how the system works without having to update core files.)

Comment: I figured out that if a theme is installed code should go to the theme's functions.php. This solved the Error 500 but not the initial problem. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40295/239079) where it states the priority of functions.php must be increased. How would one do that?

Comment: You can change the priority of your filter by changing `add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_new_custom_mime_types' );` to `add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_new_custom_mime_types', 1 );`. The 3rd parameter is the priority; lower number means higher priority. The default is `10`.

Comment: Thanks, does not help. Now I got three out of eight mods. Only five to go! Why do they make this so complicated?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Upload file type not permitted even if explicitly registered as upload_filetypes in the db (multisite)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253112/upload-file-type-not-permitted-even-if-explicitly-registered-as-upload-filetypes). Use [WP Add MIME types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-mime-types/) as the workaround.